# whats is DotNetTestRunner responder=fitClient?

Tags: .net, command-line, fitnesse

I downloaded the deprecated DotNetTestRunner source and understand that a responder, when making a HTTP request to fitServer, is basically an action to take with the test. But in the DotNetTestRunner code it sends responder=fitClient. What is this?

Answer (score 0):

It tells FitNesse that this request is coming from an independent 'client' process rather a process that was spawned by FitNesse.  This code has been around since about 2003, before I was involved, so I don't know much about the reasons behind it.

Comment: Is there a way to keep that behavior but also add a "suite" responder as well? The problem Im having with it is it wont run the suite with its setup, but rather each individual test (without running the setup first, causing failures)

Comment: I don't know much about that area of FitNesse. You might get some answers on http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/fitnesse/